# Reading bunch of rows vs Reading a column slice from one row in cassandra. Which is faster and why? How disk seeks happen in each case?

Tags: cassandra

Reading bunch of rows vs Reading a column slice from one row in cassandra.Which is faster and why? How disk seeks happen in each case?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you run cassandra on a single node; reading many columns from one row is faster than reading multiple rows.

When you request a column slice you only need to contact 1 node; on the other fetching N rows 
hand requires you to contact M nodes (where M is between 1 and N).

This happens because rows are stored completely on nodes.

For some extend the same applies to disk seek count; if you use levelled compaction chances are that you will only need a single disk seek per column slice.

Comment: Thanks for the response! what is levelled compaction? How do I specify it when I am creating a columnfamily/table?

Comment: @user1870400 plenty of docs on datastax website about it: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/leveled-compaction-in-apache-cassandra make sure levelled compaction is good for you before you start using it:) (http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/when-to-use-leveled-compaction)